# Triggering transformations from report results in BI server

Tags: report, pentaho, business-intelligence

is there a capability or function in BI server to manually run a transformation that would act on the results of the report?

like for example you would retrieve records that are tagged as 'NEW' using a pentaho report designer file deployed on the server. After being provided of results, I would like to act on those 'NEW' records and do some processing with them then tag them as 'OLD' using a transformation through a button.

is this possible? someone told me of xactions but i have the faintest idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating a set of instructions using xactions that would call some transformation and work on the user input, I just created the procedure in the database and called it from a prpt file. http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?77311-Call-procedure-with-report-designer-3-6

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering, why would you want the BI tool to perform the action. Why not do it in the database itself?

Vijay.

Comment: yeah, that probably is the best option. i just figured out recently that procedures can be called from a prpt file by using a specific syntax. http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?77311-Call-procedure-with-report-designer-3-6